# Subversion administrator password

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I've installed SVN on Windows using [VisualSVN Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VisualSVN#VisualSVN_Server). I can add users, repositories, groups, etc. using the SVN manager GUI application. Presumably when I'm using this application, I'm authenticated to SVN as the administrator or root user.

I guess VisualSVN uses a default administrator username and password, because it didn't prompt me to choose one during installation. What is this default, and how I would go about changing it?

The server is using Subversion authentication.

Answer (score 2):

[Visual SVN Installation](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/) by default uses integrated security, but you can change it in the Server managment GUI. You should find most of the information here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "administrator" password in VisualSVN Server. The only members of local Administrators and "VisualSVN Server Admins" Windows groups have permissions to manage VisualSVN Server instance locally or remotely over WMI.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Server and create user , Simple and then if prompted while checking out, Enter the same username and password...